# How to paste the columns from a file to another temp file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have edited the previous question since it was way too long and annoying, now that I have figured out the things I wanted I see there is one minor glitch in some operation in the below code. Seek advice.

I have code and now it works as I expect but I get an additional row with 0, am not being able to understand why? any advice?

code

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash

cd /path/vdas/client/ChIP-Seq/output/merge_MACS2_peaks_patient_specific/EOC/test

cut -f 1,2,3 /path/vdas/client/ChIP-Seq/output/merge_MACS2_peaks_patient_specific/EOC/test_merge.bed > tmp
printf "chr\tstart\tend" > tsamples
for file in `ls *.bed`; do
    printf "\t" >> tsamples
    printf `basename $file .bed` >> tsamples
    #echo $file | cut -d_ -f 1,2,3 >> tsamples
    intersectBed -wao -a /path/vdas/client/ChIP-Seq/output/merge_MACS2_peaks_patient_specific/EOC/test_merge.bed -b $file -f 0.20 | cut -f 9 | tail -n+1 | paste tmp - > tmp2
    mv tmp2 tmp
done
echo "" >> tsamples
cat tsamples tmp > histone_marks.map
rm tsamples tmp
```

Output

```
chr start   end test_K27ac_S12818   test_K27ac_S12838   test_K27me3_S12815_5cols    test_K27me3_S12830_5cols    test_K4me1_S12816   test_K4me1_S12831   test_K4me1_S12836
chr1    754118  754696  0   0   0   0   290 576 0
chr1    804929  805633  0   0   704 0   277 0   704
chr1    826069  826438  0   0   0   0   369 0   0
chr1    839340  839608  0   0   268 0   268 0   0
chr1    840388  843628  0   0   3240    0   816 2434    923
chr1    845517  847768  0   0   2251    820 1113    2106    1677
chr1    850950  854146  0   0   3196    3196    2184    3196    1302
chr1    855361  857280  0   0   1919    0   1911    1919    979
chr1    857930  859278  0   0   1348    0   1139    1125    923
chr1    859906  860677  351 0   771 463 0   0   771
    0
```

Everything is fine except the last row shows a 0, do not know why?? any advice

Comment: Your problem is in your printf statement before intersectBed: remove the comma after the number 3 in your printf statement

Comment: Yes I figured it out , thanks but the problem is the output does not have the header and also I want the output to have typical headers of the file name and the first 3 fields of the output files to be merged as in my output mentioend

Comment: If you have answered the question yourself, please consider posting the answer and accepting it.

Comment: No actually the answer is not entirely correct. I need some suggestions. I figured it out a way how to makes the changes but there is some additional row am getting which I should not. How can I put the entire code which I made and the desired output I got. Thanks

Comment: @pcantalupo I edited my query can you tell me why I am getting such last row as 0?

Comment: Your question is way too long, partly because you have multiple versions of the code and output. If you provide a minimal example, more people will really read it and you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Yes I have edited the question and now I have only one a precise query. Thanks @MichaelJaros

Comment: `man cut` is the answer to all your problems.  The `cut(1)` command redirected to the new file will do the work.

Comment: @LuisColorado is it because of the non delimiter fields being selected with the cut command?

Comment: It does not work, there is some problem with the intersectBed operation I am doing,, too many extra rows at the end. I am not sure why and how is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I am doing it correct so I did the change of the code myself and this is how I did it

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash

cd /path/vdas/client/ChIP-Seq/output/merge_MACS2_peaks_patient_specific/EOC/test

cut -f 1,2,3 /path/vdas/client/ChIP-Seq/output/merge_MACS2_peaks_patient_specific/EOC/test_merge.bed > tmp
printf "chr\tstart\tend" > tsamples
for file in `ls *.bed`; do
    printf "\t" >> tsamples
    printf `basename $file .bed` >> tsamples
    #echo $file | cut -d_ -f 1,2,3 >> tsamples
    intersectBed -wao -a /path/vdas/client/ChIP-Seq/output/merge_MACS2_peaks_patient_specific/EOC/test_merge.bed -b $file -f 0.20 | cut -f 9 | tail -n+1 | paste tmp - > tmp2
    mv tmp2 tmp
done
echo "" >> tsamples
cat tsamples tmp > histone_marks.map
rm tsamples tmp
sed '$d' histone_marks.map
```

This does work but I know it is a very crude way to do it. I could not figure out why the last row 0 is coming out but it is with some kind of operation I believe with bash but not for the intesectBed operation since the columns are pretty fine.